# Trying to install react-native-lottie-splash-screen on Android but com.test_lottiesplash:color/white not found

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

> ```
> * What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
>    > Android resource linking failed
>      ERROR:D:\Apps\ReactNative\myProducts\Test_LottieSplash\android\app\src\main\res\layout\launch_screen.xml:10: AAPT: error: resource color/white (aka com.test_lottiesplash:color/white) not found.
> ```

[image]